# "Apply a patch" vs. "Install a patch"

Tags: word-choice

One of my peers insist that one should say "install a patch". I believe on the contrary that "apply a patch" is more natural and one can only "install a program" when it comes to piece of software.

A quick search in google tells me that the words *apply* and *patch* are more often associated as the words *install* and *patch*. There is nonetheless a lot of result for it, and searching for "install a patch" is more succesful as searching for "apply a patch".

Knowing that a google search is not ideal to find an answer in this domain, I would like to know when using *apply* is favored, and when it is better to use *install* with the word *patch*.

Comment: I would apply a patch to a program I had installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Apply a patch* seems more natural, to me, as it reminds me of *apply a patch* referred to a piece of cloth applied to a weak point.
I also normally use the word *patch* when referring to an operation made to source code.

*Install a patch* would mean to run an installation program that patches an application, or a file present on a computer.

Instead of using *apply a patch*, or *install a patch*, I would use *patch* as a verb.
As reported by the NOAD, *to patch* means, when used in computing contexts, "correct, enhance, or modify (a routine or program) by inserting a patch".

Comment: Agree, though "to patch" could also refer to the creation of a patch...

Comment: I think of applying a patch as a manual process (e.g. using a hex editor and manually changing values). Installing a patch is what most people do: download and run an installer. To confuse matters more: when I think of the old-fashioned patch metaphor, I think of sewing/ironing a patch!

Comment: @horatio: Would running a script be considered as running in installer in this case?

Comment: @Eldros: If the script is something like `patch`, to which you need to provide the right arguments to obtain the right effect, then I would not call of installer. If it's a script that does all, and eventually ask optional parameters, then I would call it installer. The distinction is not so clear, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think “apply a patch” is much more in line with the pre-computer era usage of the word “patch”, and so might fit better with the image conveyed by the word (the analogy between a cloth patch and the software patch).

Both options are perfectly understandble, however, which is the most important issue!

Answer (score 1):

*Install* implies that something is individual or separate (a component or an entire program) ; *apply* refers to something that is added to enhance an existing component.

Answer (score 1):

"Apply a patch" is correct, in my view. This usage goes back to at least the mid-1960s on mainframe computers. I speak from personal experience!